# PHP Captcha can't find the TTF file

Tags: php, captcha

I need to add a captcha to my site but for some reason I get this error (from the log file):

```
Warning: imagettfbbox(): Could not find/open font in /home/eric/www/captcha.php on line 24
Warning: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /home/eric/www/captcha.php on line 27
```

Here's my code:

```
function generate($width,$height,$characters='6') {
    $code = '';
    $availableChar = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $characters) { 
        $code .= substr($availableChar, mt_rand(0, strlen($availableChar)-1), 1);
        $i++;
    }
    $image = imagecreate($width, $height);
    $text = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
    $things = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 120, 180);
    for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
        imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $things);
    }
    for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
        imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $things);
    }
    $textbox = imagettfbbox($height, 0, 'monofont.ttf', $code);
    imagettftext($image, $height, 0, (($width - $textbox[4])/2), (($height - $textbox[5])/2), $text, 'monofont.ttf' , $code);
    imagejpeg($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
    return $code;
}

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$code = generate(100, 40, 5);
echo $_SESSION['security_code'] = $code;
```

and the file in my folder:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tech4wilco tech4wilco 41036 1999-07-13 23:30 monofont.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tech4wilco tech4wilco  1030 2011-10-17 15:43 captcha.php
```

I did some digging and what I found is the font needs to be there and as you can see it's in the same folder as the PHP file, Am I not understanding something?

Comment: You don't do any error checking. All of those functions (like imagejpeg) return booleans or other info that indicates their succes. Catch those results and narrow down where it goed wrong.

Comment: It might have to do with the GD library you're using. From the PHP docs, "Depending on which version of the GD library that PHP is using, it may attempt to search for files that do not begin with a leading '/' by appending '.ttf' to the filename and searching along a library-defined font path." Perhaps it was looking for monofont.ttf.ttf?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's probably looking in the wrong directory.  Try changing `monofont.ttf` to `./monofont.ttf`.

Answer (score 1):

Its not in the same folder as the PHP file, since you are runing Test.php and not Captcha.php.
Try putting it on the same folder as test.php or using the correct path to get to it.

Comment: sorry my bad, I renamed the file afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

`monofont.ttf` file is not there in the directory.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: this answer is for above question